# Unable to load username into database

Tags: php, mysql

I had this code working previously, and now I cannot get it working again.  The password loads into the database fine, but the username won't.  The username is labelled correctly.  When it loads, the username is blank.  Please help.

I keep getting the following error:

> Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\signup.php on line 55.

I know what the error means.  I just don't now why $createusername is not reading as a parameter...

```
<?php
    $createusername = (isset($_GET['createusername']) ? $_GET['createusername'] : null);
$createpassword = (isset($_POST['createpassword']) ? $_POST['createpassword'] : null);
$confirmpassword = (isset($_POST['confirmpassword']) ? $_POST['confirmpassword'] : null);


function unique_salt() {
    return substr(sha1(mt_rand()),0,22);
}
$unique_salt = unique_salt();


function myhash($createpassword, $unique_salt) {
    return crypt($createpassword, '$2y$10$'.$unique_salt);
}
$myhash = myhash($createpassword, $unique_salt);

$con=mysqli_connect("mysite","mylogin","mypassword","mydatabase");


if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to database." . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$sql=mysqli_query("INSERT INTO Users (username, password) VALUES ('$createusername', '$myhash')");


if($createpassword != $confirmpassword) {
    trigger_error("The passwords do not match.");
}else {
$sql;
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>

<

div style="color:#000047;margin-top:60px;">
<form id='newuser' accept-charset='UTF-8' style='margin-top:-45px;'> 
<fieldset > 
<legend style="font-family:verdana;color:#000047;">New User</legend> 
<input type='hidden' name='submitted' id='submitted' value='1'/>   
<label for='createusername' >Create UserName:</label> 
<input type='text' id='createusername'  method='get' maxlength="50" style="background-color:#000047;color:#FFFFFF;"/>   
<label for='createpassword' >Create Password:</label> 
<input type='text' id='createpassword' method='post' maxlength="50" style="background-color:#000047;color:#FFFFFF;"/>
<label for='createpassword' >Confirm Password:</label> 
<input type='text' id='confirmpassword' method='post' maxlength="50" style="background-color:#000047;color:#FFFFFF;"/>
<input type="image" id="login2" method='post' src="/images/submit.jpg" alt="Submit" style="vertical-align:bottom" />    
</fieldset> 
</form> 
</div>
<h3>Please sign in after registration.</h3>
<a href="index.php"><h3>Sign In</h3></a>
```

Comment: just add `$con` on `mysqli_query()`

Comment: ***Question***: Wouldn't you `if($createpassword != $confirmpassword)` before inserting any values into the database?

Comment: I moved that if($createpassword != $confirmpassword) statement before the INSERT INTO statement and the result is the same.  Also worth noting, when the passwords are incorrect, the error is not triggered.

Comment: @user3709138 that would be because you dont hash the `$confirmpassword` variable...

Comment: Can you show the form html?

Comment: It worked previously without me hashing it.  It is based off of the input prior to hashing it.

Comment: Absolutely.  I'm adding it above.

Comment: Most likely your form is using a POST method, because two of your conditionals are POST, while the first one is GET. Try changing `$createusername = (isset($_GET['createusername']) ? $_GET['createusername'] : null);` to `$createusername = (isset($_POST['createusername']) ? $_POST['createusername'] : null);` - However seeing full code and/or the form stand to confirm this.

Comment: I tried that.  I started to already.  Sorry, I should have said that.  I remember the first time that using the GET method was the only way I could get it to work.  I thought it was weird.  That's why I had to delete name="", so it wouldn't show in the URL.

Comment: *I tried that already.  Sorry...bad grammar.

Comment: Ok, I just noticed you had the form in there. As is stands, your form has no method so it defaults to GET. Plus, you're using 2x POST conditionals. Those won't work. Either you add `method="post"` and use my other suggestion, or change all of your `$_POST` to `$_GET`

Comment: Plus this `<input type="image" id="login2" method='post'` aaahhhh I see now. Remove the `method='post'` from in there. That's invalid. It belongs in `form`

Comment: @Fred-ii- sorry to steal your thunder good sir ;-)

Comment: I'm putting my answer now. @Darren

Comment: @user3709138 Consult my answer and go over it carefully, there are a lot of important notes. There is an alternate method in there too. I've tested it.

Comment: Both of you have been amazing.  I have it up and running again with both of your help.  Thanks for the explanation on the HTML forms as well.  I had no idea.

Comment: I do all the work, good one. Someone uses my comments and makes it their own. Classic. This is the last answer I'm putting in. I'm officially retired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## For a better answer, view Fred -ii- 's answer here.

---

Your form explains it all. You are processing it the wrong way. What you should have is a form  that looks something like this:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <fieldset > 
        <legend style="font-family:verdana;color:#000047;">New User</legend> 
        <input type='hidden' name='submitted' id='submitted' value='1'/>   
        <label for='createusername' >Create UserName:</label> 
        <input type='text' id='createusername' name="createusername" maxlength="50" style="background-color:#000047;color:#FFFFFF;"/>   
        <label for='createpassword' >Create Password:</label> 
        <input type='text' id='createpassword' name="createpassword" maxlength="50" style="background-color:#000047;color:#FFFFFF;"/>
        <label for='createpassword' >Confirm Password:</label> 
        <input type='text' id='confirmpassword' name="confirmpassword" maxlength="50" style="background-color:#000047;color:#FFFFFF;"/>
        <input type="image" id="login2" src="/images/submit.jpg" alt="Submit" style="vertical-align:bottom" />    
    </fieldset> 
</form>
```

As you can see, your form `input` elements do **not** need a `method` tag. However; they do need a `name` tag as you can see we specified in the form above.

That will allow you to access the `$_POST` array and grab your variables:

```
$createusername = (isset($_POST['createusername']) ? $_POST['createusername'] : null);
$createpassword = (isset($_POST['createpassword']) ? $_POST['createpassword'] : null);
$confirmpassword = (isset($_POST['confirmpassword']) ? $_POST['confirmpassword'] : null);
```

I mean, they did make guidelines for a reason. So following them would only be practical.

---

#### Some Reading

- [HTML Forms: The right way](http://www.newmediacampaigns.com/blog/html-forms-the-right-ways)
- [How to structure a HTML Form](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/How_to_structure_an_HTML_form)

Comment: Good for you. I'm officially retired. All the best.

Comment: @Fred-ii- You're not going, won't let you! If it takes me deleting this answer then so be it! You say the word <3

Comment: It's ok Darren, it's not your fault. I have been giving comments-only (answers) for some time now which suited me fine. I kind of came out of retirement with this one. I'm not deleting my account, I'm just not giving official answers (anymore). *Plus,* what with the way that SO's mentality's changed in the past few weeks, I'm not going to be part of it. You keep going the way you are, you're doing good. Cheers. ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- Keep in mind that most of the SO community aren't going to let you go easily. I for one won't be. You're more than an asset to this website! And I couldn't agree more with your last statement! :-( but its the circle of life isn't it!

Answer (score 2):

#### You've seen it here folks, this is the last answer you'll see from good 'ol Fred.

#### I am officially retiring from giving answers. It's comments only help.

---

As is stands, your form has no method so it defaults to GET. Plus, you're using 2x POST conditionals. Those won't work. Either you add `method="post"` inside `<form...` and use my other suggestion, or change all of your `$_POST` to `$_GET`

Plus this `<input type="image" id="login2" method='post'` aaahhhh I see now. Remove the `method='post'` from in there. That's invalid. It belongs in `form`

Also, you were using methods inside your inputs and were not named which is invalid, but with `id`s only.

I am however uncertain about a few things.

this:

```
else {
$sql;
}
```

and `trigger_error()` - I see no function of that name in your code, which could very well explain why you're not getting an error stating that the passwords don't match.

> Your comment: *"Also worth noting, when the passwords are incorrect, the error is not triggered."*

If you don't have such a function, either replace it with an echo, then an `exit()` or `die()` which I have done.

Your query belongs where the `$sql;` is, and not just a stray variable.

Another thing is that you're not passing DB connection to your query:

`$sql=mysqli_query($con,"INSERT...` is what should be used.

Sidenote: `type="text"` for password fields are not recommended. Those have been changed to `type="password"`

Use this instead, however I suggest you use two different files. One for your form and one for your PHP/SQL. As it stands, your code will try and connect and do the query right away. The usual method is to see if all fields are not empty along to see if the submit button is set, but that's up to you. The following works.

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

$createusername = (isset($_POST['createusername']) ? $_POST['createusername'] : null);
$createpassword = (isset($_POST['createpassword']) ? $_POST['createpassword'] : null);
$confirmpassword = (isset($_POST['confirmpassword']) ? $_POST['confirmpassword'] : null);


function unique_salt() {
    return substr(sha1(mt_rand()),0,22);
}
$unique_salt = unique_salt();

function myhash($createpassword, $unique_salt) {
    return crypt($createpassword, '$2y$10$'.$unique_salt);
}
$myhash = myhash($createpassword, $unique_salt);

$con=mysqli_connect("mysite","mylogin","mypassword","mydatabase");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to database." . mysqli_connect_error();
}

if($createpassword != $confirmpassword) {
    // trigger_error("The passwords do not match.");
    
    die("The passwords do not match.");
}else {

$sql=mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO Users (username, password) VALUES ('$createusername', '$myhash')");
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>

<div style="color:#000047;margin-top:60px;">
<form id='newuser' accept-charset='UTF-8' style='margin-top:-45px;' method='post'> 
<fieldset> 
<legend style="font-family:verdana;color:#000047;">New User</legend> 
<input type='hidden' name='submitted' id='submitted' value='1'/>   
<label for='createusername' >Create UserName:</label> 
<input type='text' name='createusername' id='createusername' maxlength="50" style="background-color:#000047;color:#FFFFFF;"/>   
<label for='createpassword' >Create Password:</label> 
<input type='password' name='createpassword' id='createpassword' maxlength="50" style="background-color:#000047;color:#FFFFFF;"/>
<label for='confirmpassword'>Confirm Password:</label> 
<input type='password' name='confirmpassword' id='confirmpassword' maxlength="50" style="background-color:#000047;color:#FFFFFF;"/>
<input type="image" id="login2" src="/images/submit.jpg" alt="Submit" style="vertical-align:bottom" />    
</fieldset> 
</form> 
</div>
<h3>Please sign in after registration.</h3>
<a href="index.php"><h3>Sign In</h3></a>
```

---

Alternate method checking for empty fields:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

$createusername = (isset($_POST['createusername']) ? $_POST['createusername'] : null);
$createpassword = (isset($_POST['createpassword']) ? $_POST['createpassword'] : null);
$confirmpassword = (isset($_POST['confirmpassword']) ? $_POST['confirmpassword'] : null);

function unique_salt() {
    return substr(sha1(mt_rand()),0,22);
}
$unique_salt = unique_salt();

function myhash($createpassword, $unique_salt) {
    return crypt($createpassword, '$2y$10$'.$unique_salt);
}
$myhash = myhash($createpassword, $unique_salt);

$con=mysqli_connect("mysite","mylogin","mypassword","mydatabase");

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
      echo "Failed to connect to database." . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    if($createpassword != $confirmpassword) {
        // trigger_error("The passwords do not match.");

        die("The passwords do not match.");
    }

if(!empty($_POST['createusername']) && !empty($_POST['createpassword']) && !empty($_POST['confirmpassword']) ){
    $sql=mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO Users (username, password) VALUES ('$createusername', '$myhash')");

if($sql){
echo "Success";
}

    else{
    throw new Exception($con->error);
    }
}

mysqli_close($con);

?>

<div style="color:#000047;margin-top:60px;">

<form id='newuser' accept-charset='UTF-8' style='margin-top:-45px;' method='post'>

<fieldset> 
<legend style="font-family:verdana;color:#000047;">New User</legend> 
<input type='hidden' name='submitted' id='submitted' value='1'/>   
<label for='createusername' >Create UserName:</label> 
<input type='text' name='createusername' id='createusername' maxlength="50" style="background-color:#000047;color:#FFFFFF;"/>   
<label for='createpassword' >Create Password:</label> 
<input type='password' name='createpassword' id='createpassword' maxlength="50" style="background-color:#000047;color:#FFFFFF;"/>
<label for='confirmpassword'>Confirm Password:</label> 
<input type='password' name='confirmpassword' id='confirmpassword' maxlength="50" style="background-color:#000047;color:#FFFFFF;"/>
<input type="image" id="login2" src="/images/submit.jpg" alt="Submit" style="vertical-align:bottom" />    
</fieldset> 
</form>

</div>
<h3>Please sign in after registration.</h3>
<a href="index.php"><h3>Sign In</h3></a>
```

Comment: @are you serious about not answering questions anymore?

Comment: @JohnConde I sure am John. I'm strictly comments-based from hereon in. Very long story, but I'll send you a PM soon.

Comment: That's a shame. :( Looking forward to your message.

Comment: @JohnConde I'm still involved in the community ;-) cheers amico mio

Answer (score 0):

In your query, you need to provide the connection:

```
$sql = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO Users (username, password) VALUES ('$createusername', '$myhash')");
```

If you use the [object oriented](https://www.php.net/mysqli_query) version, you don't need to pass in the connection as it's stored in the object.

---

As a side note, your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You can fix this by filtering the input or using [parameterised queries](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: Thank you both.  I added the connection via $con.  I do remember using that previously.  I am still getting an empty username.  Anymore suggestions?

Comment: @user3709138 `echo $createusername` and see if anything is getting output.